# How to find RTT in scapy?

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, roundtrip

I am using scapy + Python and I need to find the round trip time of a packet.
How can I do this? 
I have looked everywhere so dont tell me that there is info on this subject out there. 
Looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity let's suppose both the outgoing and the incoming packets are captured in "tmp.pcap", and that they are the only two packets captured in that file. Then:

```
pkts = rdpcap("tmp.pcap")
roundTripTime = pkts[1].time - pkts[0].time
```